# Need a help on setting Reinstallmode and Reinstall

Tags: installation, windows-installer

Im having MSI ,for minor update ,i will be updating only build number with no product code change. i try to paramters to msiexex .
msiexec /i sample.msi Reinstall=ALL ReinstallMode=amus in command prompt.Inspite of setting in command prompt,I tried to update msi property through orca. I added 2 properties to Reinstallmode and reinstall properties to orca.But they are not working.It gives me error message.Product of same version has already installed.

one more question which i had is 
I tried to set custom action condition property = "Not Installed" .SO tht during repair mode ,i will not invoke custom action.Only one time invokation.
If i try to run msiexec /i sample.msi Reinstallmode=amus Reinstall="All" will custom action be invoked or it will not invoke.

~Mahender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the properties you pass are not set because you missed the correct spelling. Both REINSTALL and REINSTALLMODE properties should be all UPPERCASE. Such uppercased properties are called public properties, and only public properties can be passed via command line.

Hope this helps.